# copy multiple objects into one object in amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I stuck with the following problem: I need to upload objects in small parts (512KB), so I can not use multipart upload (since the minimum 5MB restriction). On the grounds of that, I have to put my parts in a "partitions" bucket and run a Cron task to download partitions and upload a single concatenated object into a "completed" bucket.

I would like to clarify, however, that there is no more elegant way to do this except direct download and concatenation. AWS CLI [suggests](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/) one can copy objects as a whole, but I see no way to copy *and concatenate* several objects into one. Is there a way to do this via AWS S3 means?

UPD: I am not guaranteed 512KB chunk size (in fact, it is 512KB to 16MB), but it is usually 512KB and this limit takes origin from vendor of my IP cameras so I can not really change that. And I know the result size beforehead, the camera tells me "I am going to upload 33MB" with a separate call to my backend, but I have no control over number of chunks or their size except the guaranteed boundaries above.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you can only upload in small parts? Are they always exactly 512KB? Is it binary data, text data, etc? How big is the final object (or how many parts)? What would 'signal' the upload of the final part so that the parts can be combined? Feel free to edit your question to provide these details.

Comment: There is an `upload_part_copy()` command that can copy multiple existing objects into a new object, but it seems each part must be a minimum of 5MB.